# .Net Web Method Access

Tags: jquery

I am having some problems accessing a .net webmethod for from a server different to the one the web services are stored on.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/login",
    data: "{'username':'test'," + "'password':'test'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

When the above jQuery is executed, the method runs as expected.  If I run the same code on a different server and change the url to where it is stored, the webmethod does not appear execute.  Firebug displays an error but I can't pin down the cause.  If I navigate to the WebService.asmx the method is listed, however I can't seem to access it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please.... NEVER EVER IN YOUR LIFE create JSON using string methods. ALWAYS Use `JSON.stringify()` for it!

Comment: You are sending invalid JSON (JSON requires doublequotes). That might break things.

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the same code on a different server and change the url to where it is stored...

If you're changing it to a URL on another domain, it will violate the browsers cross-domain sandbox and not work. The call you're making needs to be to the same domain as what served the page/script.

Comment: That's pretty obvious - can't believe I didn't think of that.  A javascript error would have been nice though, that way I could have saved a few hours of head scratching.  Thanks.  Outside of javascript, I should be ok to run this method from a different server?

Comment: Yeah, assuming things like session state, etc. are out of the picture.

Comment: Though I'm not aware of any implementation for it with "ASMX" web services, it takes only a few WCF config changes (.NET 4.0+ only) to run a JSONP web service which will support cross-domain calls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx